# Using conditional for computed Vue properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue in a site and I have a working button which changes state (If button says pause and is clicked it changes to say resume, as well as changing the colors)

The button functionality here works perfectly on the page but I'm having an issue making it line up with a value on the same page. I have another function that has an object called `details` and that has a value called `status` which can be "H" or "P"

All I need to do now is resolve this so that on page load, if the status is "H" the button says 'Resume' and if it's "P" the button says Pause (essentially, if "H" then !this.isOpen, and if "P" then this.isOpen)

How can I change this for page load so that if status is H this.isOpen is false, and if it's P this.isOpen is true? I can't do an if/conditional in the data return but maybe I could use computed properties somehow?

```
<button class="btn btn-block" :style ="{ color: pauseButton.textColor, backgroundColor:pauseButton.background, border:none, borderRadius: .15 }" v-on:click="pauseTask" type="button" role="button" id="" aria-expanded="false">
  {{ pauseButton.text }}
</button>

data() {
    return {
        details: [],
        pauseButton: {
            text:'Pause',
            textColor: '#6c757d',
            background: '#BDE5F8'
        },
        isOpen: true,
    }
},
pauseTask: function() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

      //this is the new line that doesn't work the way I need
      if(this.details[0].status === 'H'){
        !this.isOpen;
      }

      this.pauseButton.text = this.isOpen ? 'Pause' : 'Resume';
      this.pauseButton.background = this.isOpen ? '#BDE5F8' : '#FEEFB3';
      this.pauseButton.textColor = this.isOpen ? '#6c757d' : '#ff6e6e ';
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `details` is an Array and you are looping it to create multiple elements, you should follow a method like below to simplify it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      details: [{
        status: 'H'
      }, {
        status: 'H'
      }, {
        status: 'P'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTask(d) {
      d.status = (d.status == 'H' ? 'P' : 'H')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: .15;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.btn.resume {
  color: #ff6e6e;
  background-color: #FEEFB3;
}

.btn.pause {
  color: #6c757d;
  background-color: #BDE5F8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(d, i) in details" :key="i">
    Status: {{ d.status}}
    <button 
      :class="['btn', 'btn-block', d.status == 'H' ? 'resume' : 'pause']" 
      @click="toggleTask(d)" 
      role="button" 
      aria-expanded="false">
      {{ d.status == 'H' ? 'Resume' : 'Pause' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So ```details``` is structured as an array but I"m only ever returning one thing there (hence the [0]) but I think this will still work

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the `isOpen` value to `!isOpen` only when it's 'H' in the `mounted` or `created` lifecycle method.

```
mounted(){
  if(this.details[0].status === 'H'){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
},
pauseTask: function() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

      this.pauseButton.text = this.isOpen ? 'Pause' : 'Resume';
      this.pauseButton.background = this.isOpen ? '#BDE5F8' : '#FEEFB3';
      this.pauseButton.textColor = this.isOpen ? '#6c757d' : '#ff6e6e ';
    },
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue on page load though. status is 'H' on page load but removing the info from the data return doesn't show the button. When I do get it to show then clicking doesn't change

Comment: ok I see your edit now. I think that makes sense but how does that affect my data return on page load?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that you said you want to change the state on page load. On page load, Vue.js triggers `created` and `mounted` lifecycle methods. You can check and write the logic there. I changed the code above.

Comment: Yes that is correct but what do I do about the pauseButton in my data return?

Comment: The text and color are dependent on the P or the H as well

Comment: You can do the same as you've done in the `pauseTask` function. Just conditionally change the state in the mounted hook.